# Covert ../ Into Real Directories PHP

Tags: php, javascript, directory, scandir

I am making a small file browsing script using PHP and Javascript and I have come into a small issue. The current directory is stored as GET in the url as `index.php?dir=/projects/jphp` when it is in the base. I then store this in the variabe `$scandir` using:

```
$scandir = $_GET['dir'];
```

as the fiels are listed in a table so users can look thorugh them, folders are hyperlinked like this:

```
<td><a style="color: red;" href="edit.php?pid=<?php echo $project['id'] ?>&dir=<?php echo $scandir . "/" . $thisfile; ?>"><?php echo $thisfile; ?></a></td>
```

The variable `$thisfile` is populated using a `foreach()` loop that goes through every file in the directory.

As The user starts to browse the folders and files, the file address gets messy so, for example, after a minute of browsing the files, the `$_GET['dir'];` looks like

```
projects/jphp/js/../js/../../../projects/jphp
```

is there any way to keep the paths simple as the path above is the exact same as

```
projects/jphp
```

If you know how to covert the top into the bottom, that would be great, thanks! I might not have explained this well so let me know you I am not making sense.

Comment: Be sure you understand the implications of [RFI](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_File_Inclusion Remote File Inclusion)

Comment: Yeah, I recommend against doing that dynamically/with user input considering the security implications.

Comment: Personally I find that local apps hacked together have the potential to become problematic 'cause they could always become internet public in the event someone is like "well, accessing it here on the local network is fine, but I'd really like to like to access it from home or on the road" and the like.  But as long as you're aware of the dangers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`realpath()`](http://php.net/realpath#refsect1-function.realpath-examples) does what you're looking for. If you're not getting any results, check your folder permissions:

```
The running script must have executable permissions 
on all directories in the hierarchy, otherwise 
realpath() will return FALSE.
```

Comment: But That returns C:\xampp\htdocs\ide\projects\jphp. I would rather it be in the form projects/jphp (With the / not \ )

Comment: Just replace forward slash with backward slash afterwards... Doesn't seem like a big deal :)

Comment: It changes it to \ because that's how Windows does it. As Shai says, simply do a `str_replace`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may replace your links like `&dir=/some/path/../` with `&dir=/some/`, so just link not to `/some/path/../`, but to `/some/`, they are equal.

**UPD:**

For, example:

```
<?php
$dir = $scandir;
if( $dir=='..' ){
    if( $scandir=='' || $scandir=='/' ){
        // skip this entry using continue or something else
    }
    if( substr($scandir,-1)=='/' ){
        $dir = dirname(substr($scandir,0,-1)).'/';        
    }else{
        $dir = dirname($scandir).'/';
    }
    if( $dir=='' ){
        $dir = '/';
    }
}else{
    $dir = $scandir.'/'.$thisfile;
}
?>
<td><a style="color: red;" href="edit.php?pid=<?php echo $project['id'] ?>&dir=<?php echo $dir; ?>"><?php echo $thisfile; ?></a></td>
```